# Deleting rows based on multiple criteria across 2 workbooks in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 workbooks. 1 used as the Master and 1 that it ran out of Oracle Cloud on a daily basis with new information relevant to the Master Workbook. I want to compare two values between workbooks and if there is a match delete the corresponding row in the Master spreadsheet. The columns in question are column A in both workbooks which is a unique number identifying the invoice and column AB which either is "PAID" or "UNPAID" but should only be used to determine if the row should be deleted or updated between workbooks.

If the value in column AB is "PAID" and is in the daily workbook(let's call it WB2) and the value in column A of WB2 is in Master then delete the row in Master.

Below is the code that i've currently got. I've went down the route of putting both the ranges in an array and then was hoping to do something like check if the values in the array match (which i've done previously) but I'm not really sure how to then move onto deleting the corresponding row from the correct WB when the conditions have been met.

```
Public startCell As Range

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Integer
  j = 0

  For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i, 1) = stringToBeFound Then
        IsInArray = True
        j = 1
    End If
  Next i
  If j = 0 Then IsInArray = False
End Function

Sub AmendMaster()

Set startCell = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main_Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 
"A").End(xlUp)

Dim mainRng As Range
Dim newRng As Range

Dim cell As Range

Dim mainArr As Variant

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wbs(1) As Workbook


Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim RowMatch As Long
a = 0

Set mainRng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main_Data").Range("A2", ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main_Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0,27)) 'Column A is the Cust Transaction ID on the Main Report


mainArr = mainRng.Value

For Each wb In Workbooks

Set wbs(a) = wb
a = a + 1

Next wb

Set newRng = wbs(1).Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3", wbs(1).Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0,28)) 'Column A is the Cust Transaction ID on the Daily Report
newArr = newRng.Value

For Each cell In mainRng
    cell.Value = cell.Value * 1
Next cell
For Each cell in newRng
    cell.Value = cell.Value * 1
Next cell

newRng.NumberFormat = "0"
newRng.NumberFormat = "0"

mainRng = newRng.Value


For i = 1 To UBound(newArr)
match = False
For j = 1 To UBound(mainArr)
    If newArr(i,28) = "PAID" And newArr(i,1) = mainArr(j,1) THEN 
        .Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i


End Sub
```

The expected result should be if the Master spreadsheet has 10 rows that are in  WB2 and those 10 rows are in WB2 also have "PAID" in column AB then the VBA should delete the 10 matching rows in Master. If AB is "UNPAID" then although it may match then it just needs to copy and overwrite all the columns from A:V in Master workbook but for the purpose of this post i'm just wanting to focus on deleting rows as I'm pretty sure I could figure out pasting values.

Any help would be great as I've tried to understanding deleting values but not sure how to do it via array or even what's the best way to tackle this problem so i'm completely open to any tips or suggestions so I can improve coding.

If there's anything else that you need from me to better understand the problem or try please don't hesitate to let me know.

Regards,

Matt

Comment: It's not clear why you're putting two workbooks into array...

Comment: How would you suggest comparing the data between the two workbooks and deleting the rows from Master one?

Comment: Check [this workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvqfUD6Rp0UClAVo9LHHd2j36wta). `Sheet2` emulates daily worksheet and `Sheet1` - master worksheet. The idea is to filter master sheet by values from daily sheet and then check filtered range for presence of "PAID" word.

Answer (score 0):

## Lost in VBA

Cannot determine what's going on. Sorry.

```
Option Explicit

Public startCell As Range

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim i As Long

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 1) = stringToBeFound Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Function

Sub AmendMaster()

    Const cSource As Variant = "Sheet1"     ' Source Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cSrc1 As Variant = "A"            ' Source Column 1 Letter/Number
    Const cSrc2 As Variant = "AC"           ' Source Column 2 Letter/Number
    Const cSrcFirstR As Long = 3            ' Source First Row Number

    Const cTarget As Variant = "Main_Data"  ' Target Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cTgt1 As Variant = "A"            ' Target Column 1 Letter/Number
    Const cTgt2 As Variant = "AB"           ' Target Column 2 Letter/Number
    Const cTgtFirstR As Long = 2            ' Target First Row Number

    Dim ws As Worksheet     ' Source Worksheet
    Dim rngU As Range       ' Union Range
    Dim vntSrc As Variant   ' Source Array
    Dim vntTgt As Variant   ' Target Array
    Dim srcLastR As Long    ' Source Last Row Number
    Dim tgtLastR As Long    ' Target Last Row Number
    Dim i As Long           ' Array Row Counter
    Dim j As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cTarget)
        tgtLastR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cTgt1).End(xlUp).Row
        vntTgt = .Range(.Cells(cTgtFirstR, cTgt1), .Cells(tgtLastR, cTgt2))
    End With

    For i = 1 To Workbooks.Count
        If Workbooks(i).Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name _
                And Windows(Workbooks(i).Name).Visible = True Then
            Debug.Print Workbooks(i).Name
            With Workbooks(i).Worksheets(cSource)
                srcLastR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cSrc1).End(xlUp).Row
                vntSrc = .Range(.Cells(cSrcFirstR, cSrc1), _
                        .Cells(srcLastR, cSrc2))
            End With
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    For i = 1 To UBound(vntSrc)
        For j = 1 To UBound(vntTgt)
            If vntTgt(i, UBound(vntTgt, 2)) = "PAID" _
                    And vntSrc(i, 1) = vntTgt(j, 1) Then
                With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cTarget)
                    .Rows(j).Hidden = True ' Delete
                End With
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```